# Why are variables in closure not forgotten?

Tags: go, closures, fibonacci

The following code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

// fibonacci is a function that returns
// a function that returns an int.

func fibonacci() func() int {
    first, second := 0, 1

    return func() int {
        // return next fibonacci number here.
        first, second = second, first+second
        return  first
    }   
}

func main() {
    f := fibonacci()
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(f())
    }
}
```

returns 10 numbers of the fibonacci sequence. What's confusing to me is why is works. It seems like the values first and second are somehow **saved** in memory, since each time the code is executed, a new fibonacci number in sequence with the previous one is returned. I thought that functions lost their remembered variables when they were done executing. What is going on here?

Comment: Well, that's the whole point of a closure. I can recommend reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1) (it's for Javascript, not Go, but that shouldn't really matter here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`first`, and `second` are variables in the `fibonacci()` func, that were 'closed over' by the returned `func() int` that was returned from `fibonacci()`.

So they are in the closure associated with `f`, so `f` has access to those variables as long as it exists.

See [this](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/22) Go Tour slide (and the ones around it) for some explanation of Go closures.